# ClickHouse не работает DISTINCT ON

Tags: clickhouse

Имеется таблица `my_table` следующего вида:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| m | x | c | d |
| m | x | y | z |

Необходимо получить все строки с уникальными значениями из `Column2`, т.е. должно получиться нечто подобное:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| m | x | c | d |

Пытаюсь сделать с помощью `DISTINCT`, однако, на запрос:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (Column2) *
    FROM my_db.my_table
```

получаю ошибку:

```
SQL Error [62]: ClickHouse exception, code: 62, host: localhost, port: 8123; Code: 62, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 54 ('.') (line 2, col 18): .my_table. Expected one of: UNION, LIMIT, WHERE, WINDOW, end of query, HAVING, GROUP BY, INTO OUTFILE, OFFSET, PREWHERE, Comma, ORDER BY, SETTINGS, FROM, FORMAT, WITH, token (version 21.7.3.14 (official build))
```

В качестве примера использовал https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/select/distinct/

Подскажите, что я делаю неправильно? А то информация об ошибке не сильно помогла.

Comment: DISTINCT ON - это фича Постгресса. Везде есть только обычный DISTINCT - который убирает только полные дубликаты-записи. Так что определяйте критерий выбора единственной записи из группы. А там либо нумерация в CTE, либо группирующий подзапрос.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. Понял. С толку сбила документация, в которой присутствует `DISTINCT ON`, причем с примерами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DISTINCT ON](https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/sql-reference/statements/select/distinct/) добавлена, начиная с версии [v21.8](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/whats-new/changelog/#clickhouse-release-v21-8-2021-08-12).

Поэтому либо

- обновите ClickHouse
- сэмулируйте этот запрос:

```sql
SELECT
    any(Column1),
    Column2,
    any(Column3),
    any(Column4)
FROM
(
    /* emulate the test dataset */
    SELECT
        data.1 AS Column1,
        data.2 AS Column2,
        data.3 AS Column3,
        data.4 AS Column4
    FROM
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin([('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('m', 'x', 'c', 'd'), ('m', 'x', 'y', 'z')]) AS data
    )
)
GROUP BY Column2
/*
┌─any(Column1)─┬─Column2─┬─any(Column3)─┬─any(Column4)─┐
│ a            │ b       │ c            │ d            │
│ m            │ x       │ c            │ d            │
└──────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
*/
```